# PHP arrays with Ajax - Proper way to get the data?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm a complete ajax/php idiot - lets get that out of the way right now; but I've gotten to a point where I need some help.  I've been following various tutorials here and there and kind of putting together a report.

Ultimately I have a table that contains all the data I need.  I can get that data and display it appropriately in a table without issue.  I'm trying to add 'drop-down' boxes that will allow filtering based on the criteria (there is a column called 'verticals' in this table - so a dropdown will contain all the different 'verticals' from the database column - and filter the table based on the selection of the vertical)

I have the following front-end snippet called "client.php" that the client loads to get a report:

Client.php:

```
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mediacallreport.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Generic Title</title>
</head>



<body>
  <h2> Generic Reports </h2>
  <h3>Report Formatting: </h3>
  <div id="instruction">Select how you would like the data selected using the dropdowns below</div>

  <!--DROPDOWNS-->
 Vertical - 
<select name="station" id="station">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      $(function () 
      {
        $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'api.php',   //the script to call to get data          
          data: "",   //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
          dataType: 'json',   //data format      
          success: function(verticals) //on recieve of reply
          {
          for (var i in verticals)
          {
            var vertical = verticals[i];
            var verticalID = verticals[0];

        $('station').append("<option value=\""+verticalID+"\">"+verticalID+"</option>");
                }

          } 
        });
      });
    </script>
</select>

 <!--TABLE BEGINNING - TABLE HEADER ROW--> 
<table id="output">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Station_Network</th>
<th>Vertical</th>
<th>Creative</th>
<th>Tolls</th>
<th>States</th>
<th>Date Range</th>
<th>Week</th>
<th>Ordered</th>
<th>Credits</th>
<th>Credits Totals</th>
<th>Not Used</th>
<th>Cleared</th>
<th>Total Uniques</th>
<th>Cleared Each Unique</th>
<th>Total Unique Connect</th>
<th>Cleared Each Unique Connect</th>
<th>Unique Connect 8am - 8pm</th>
<th>Cleared Unique 8am - 8pm</th>
<th>Calls over 10 Min</th>
<th>Calls over 10 Min %</th>
</tr>

<!--JAVASCRIPT TO GET INFORMATION FROM DB, ASSIGN VARIABLES AND PUT INTO TABLE ROWS-->
  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function () 
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) SEND HTTP REQUEST WITH AJAX
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',   //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",   //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                        //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',   //data format      
      success: function(rows) //on recieve of reply
      {
      for (var i in rows)
      {
        var row = rows[i];
        var id = row[0];              //get id
        var station_network = row[1];       //get name
        var vertical = row[2];  //get vertical
        var creative = row[3]; //get creative
        var tolls= row[4];  //get tolls
        var states= row[5];  //get states
        var date_range= row[6];  //get date_range
        var week= row[7];  //get week
        var ordered= row[8];  //get ordered
        var credits= row[9];  //get credits
        var credit_totals= row[10];  //get credit_totals
        var not_used= row[11];
        var cleared= row[12];
        var total_uniques= row[13];
        var cleared_each_unique= row[14];
        var total_unique_connect= row[15];
        var cleared_each_unique_connect= row[16];
        var unique_connect_8am_to_8pm= row[17];
        var cleared_each_8am_to_8pm= row[18];
        var calls_over_10= row[19];
        var calls_over_10_pct= row[20];
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // DISPLAY THE CONTENT
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        //TABLES (ALTERNATING ROWS)
        if (id % 2 == 0){
        $('#output').append("<tr id=\"evenrow\"> <td>"+id+"</td><td>"+station_network+"</td><td>"+vertical+"</td><td>"+creative+"</td><td>"+tolls+"</td><td>"+states+"</td><td>"+date_range+"</td><td>"+week+"</td><td>"+ordered+"</td><td>"+credits+"</td><td>"+credit_totals+"</td><td>"+not_used+"</td><td>"+cleared+"</td><td>"+total_uniques+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_unique+"</td><td>"+total_unique_connect+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_unique_connect+"</td><td>"+unique_connect_8am_to_8pm+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_8am_to_8pm+"</td><td>"+calls_over_10+"</td><td>"+calls_over_10_pct+"</td></tr>");
        } else {
        $('#output').append("<tr id=\"oddrow\"> <td>"+id+"</td><td>"+station_network+"</td><td>"+vertical+"</td><td>"+creative+"</td><td>"+tolls+"</td><td>"+states+"</td><td>"+date_range+"</td><td>"+week+"</td><td>"+ordered+"</td><td>"+credits+"</td><td>"+credit_totals+"</td><td>"+not_used+"</td><td>"+cleared+"</td><td>"+total_uniques+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_unique+"</td><td>"+total_unique_connect+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_unique_connect+"</td><td>"+unique_connect_8am_to_8pm+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_8am_to_8pm+"</td><td>"+calls_over_10+"</td><td>"+calls_over_10_pct+"</td></tr>");
        }

        }

      } 
    });
  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

That talks to my api.php 
api.php:

```
<?php 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Connect to DB
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) ;
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //Rows of data in media-analysis
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
  $data = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
  {
  $data[] = $row;
  }



  //Dropdown for Verticals
    $verticalSql = "SELECT VERTICAL FROM media_analysis GROUP BY VERTICAL";
    $verticalResult = mysql_query($verticalSql);
    $verticalData = array();
    while ($verticalRow = mysql_fetch_row($verticalResult)){
        $verticalData[] = $verticalRow;
    }

    $finalarray = array ('rowdata' => $data, 'verticaldata' => $verticalData);
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($finalarray);
?>
```

In Firebug I can see the data coming across and it looks something like this:

```
{"rowdata":[["1","canceled","canceled","canceled","canceled","canceled","03\/18\/2013-03-24\/2013","12","canceled","0","","","0.00","0","0.00","0","0.00","0","0.00","0","0.00"],["2","Station B","Vertical B","DEBIT","800-555-5555","CA","03\/18\/2013-03-24\/2013","12","$813.00","0","","","813.00","8","101.62","5","162.60","3","271.00","2","40.00"]],"verticaldata":[["canceled"],["Vertical B"]]}
```

Before I started including the 'dropdowns', I just had a simple json_encode ($data); and it would work fine and the table displayed exactly how I wanted it to.  Since I've added another array to be passing, this is when things got crazy and I'm completely lost.

I know my coding is probably very poor, but I'm just trying to get a handle on this.  All help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the code in your success handler expects an array to be returned:

```
success: function(verticals) //on recieve of reply
{
    for (var i in verticals)
    {
        var vertical = verticals[i];
        var verticalID = verticals[0];

        $('station').append("<option value=\""+verticalID+"\">"+verticalID+"</option>");
    }

}
```

However, as you showed in your example, `verticals` looks like this:

```
{"rowdata":[[...],[...]],"verticaldata":[["canceled"],["Vertical B"]]}
```

As you can see, `verticals` is an object, that contains two other objects (`rowdata` and `verticaldata`).

To make your current success handler work again, you first need to extract `verticaldata` from the AJAX response. Simply changing the code to this should work:

```
success: function(response) //on recieve of reply
{
    var verticals = response.verticaldata;
    for (var i in verticals)
    {
        var vertical = verticals[i];
        var verticalID = verticals[0];

        $('station').append("<option value=\""+verticalID+"\">"+verticalID+"</option>");
    }
}
```

Comment: This will do it!  Thanks a ton.  I'm still a noob, but I'm learning and your explanation was exactly what I was hoping for!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

since you are using PHP and jQuery, you can use my library for that. Out-of-the-box dealing with any data that comes from PHP to Javascript, and vice-versa ;)

See here http://phery-php-ajax.net

in your case, it would be like this

```php
<?php
   include('Phery.php');

   Phery::instance()->set(array(
     'verticals' => function(data){
        $r = new PheryResponse;

        $verticalResult = mysql_query("SELECT VERTICAL FROM media_analysis GROUP BY VERTICAL");

        $r->jquery('.station'); // Select it for subsequent chaining in the loop
        $i = 0;
        while ($verticalRow = mysql_fetch_row($verticalResult)){
          $r->append('<option value="'.($i++).'">'.$verticalRow['VERTICAL'].'</option>'); // What is VERTICAL? Is that query the real one?
        }
        // every "append" call will happen to .station jquery selector automatically
        return $r;
     }
   ))->process();
?>
```

in your javascript code

```js
$(function(){
   phery.remote('verticals');
});
```

That's it. Why (re)generate data, when you can do it once in the server (where data generation belongs)

Of course, you could just return the JSON and use `phery:json`, but that's not practical in your case

```php
return PheryResponse::factory()->json($verticalData);
```

And the Javascript side

```js
phery.remote('verticals', null, null, false).on('phery:json', function(data){
  for (var i in data){
    // do your append here
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a great solution - thank you for putting it out there.  I will be checking out your library and putting that to use in the future!! Thanks!

Comment: no problem, it was made with cutting down the necessary code from client in mind, when it's about manipulating HTML directly from PHP